# MongoDB Java API: put() vs append()

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and as I going through the tutorial for Java & Mongodb. I notice there is put() and append() for BasicDBObject and I took a look at the API, put() inherit and append() is a built-in for BasicDBObject. Does anyone what is the different, such as speed of access? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [`BasicDBObject` sources](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/0322ed05816dff180f404fcb3c2f88802beee407/src/main/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.java):

```
public BasicDBObject append( String key , Object val ){
    put( key , val );
    return this;
}
```

`put()` returns the previous value, if applicable. `append()` calls `put()` internally and returns the BasicDBObject instance itself. Essentially, `append()` is a more [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for `put()`. It allows you to do something like this:

```
BasicDBObject o = new BasicDBObject().append("One", 1).append("Two", 2).append("Three", 3);
```

As far as performance goes, the JVM will *supposedly* inline methods like `append()` if they are used frequently enough somewhere. From my experience and quite a bit of profiling, however, that is not always true and you are bound to gain a little bit of speed by using `put()` directly and saving the JVM the guesswork.

That said, code readability should always be a priority. Just write your code as you feel comfortable, and benchmark/profile afterwards to find any possible optimizations. Premature optimization is a temptation that should be avoided at all costs...